# The Electric Pressure Bomb: Can a conductor rupture due to its own electric pressure?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors, elasticity, metals

So I conducted a though experiment where I take a hollow spherical conductor and beef it up with a lot of electric charge. Here, I have ignored the ionization of air due to that huge amount of charge. Okay, coming to the point, is it possible that the hollow conductor, which is made of a certain metal and let's say if that piece of metal has low elastic limit, rupture due to the effect of its own electric pressure?
If we give it enough charge for a given radius then the charge density can be made substantially high (again assuming ionization of air to be absent and that the conductor can store that amount of charge).

Answer (score 0):

The metal can be charged until its potential compensated the work function  beyond that point excess electrons prefer to be at infinity rather than on the metal surface. If the metal is polycrystalline with very low cohesion it may disintegrate, but no explosions are involved.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you're asking, but it may be closely enough related to be of interest... I've seen a tube made of aluminium foil implode when made to carry a high current (parallel to the tube axis). This is because of mutual attraction between the current-carrying 'fibres' into which we may imagine the tube to be split.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you please share a video/link related to this.

Comment: I saw this demonstrated live at The Royal Institution in London, many decades ago. Your search for a video/link would be as likely to succeed as any that I undertook.

Comment: @Philp Wood    Oh, okay. I guess i will have to conduct the experiment myself someday.